# Tengo un array que es una copia de otro ¿por qué cuando elimino un elemento del primer array se elimina en el otro?

Tags: javascript, html, array, script

Tengo una duda, les pongo un ejemplo para que sea claro:

Tengo un `array1` y el `array2` es la copia del primero. Luego, quiero eliminar solo del `array2` el elemento 12, luego imprimo en un `console.log` a ambos array, pero no entiendo por qué se eliminó del `array1` si yo no lo he tocado:

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 130, 44];
const array2 = array1;
const found = array2.findIndex(element => element === 12);

if (found > -1) {
  array2.splice(found, 1);
}

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);

//output 
[5, 130, 44]
[5, 130, 44]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no suceda esto?

Quiero eliminar del segundo `array` que es una copia del primero, pero sin que el primero resulte afectado.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232915/copying-an-array-of-objects-into-another-array-in-javascript
Aquí puedes ver tu mismo problema marcado como solucionado.

Comment: gracias, efectivamente aplicando eso  [ ... array ]  se soluciona, solo que me olvidé especificar mi problema real original, yo tengo un objeto con esta estructura  :  const array1 = [{ hola : '' , array :[5, 12, 130, 44]}]; , si guardo en otra variable , const array2 = [ ...array1 ] recibiré un error de "object is not iterable",  entonces hice const array2 = { ...array1 } y ahí si crea una copia, sin embargo cuando elimino del array2 nuevamente se elimina del array1 y no quiero que eso pase

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con esta nueva información, los comentarios no son apropiados para leer código, a ver si podemos echarte una mano

Comment: al final lo resolví de esta manera : const array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1)); , con esto pude clonar un objeto que tuviera arrays adentro, ahora ya puedo eliminar posiciones de los arrays en mi copia sin que afecte al original, al inicio creí que el problema pasaba solo con el array y hacia una copía y por eso en mi ejemplo puse ese ejemplo básico, pero al final y en realidad era todo un objeto que yo tenía que clonar y que tenía arrays adentro.

Answer (score 2):

En JavaScript se copian las referencias de los *Arrays*, de allí el efecto que mencionas:

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 130, 44];

const array2 = array1;
const found = array2.findIndex(element => element === 12);

if (found > -1) {
  array2.splice(found, 1);
}

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Por lo tanto, en la línea:

```js
const array2 = array1;
```

Se está copiando su referencia y no el *Array*.

Para copiar el *Array* solo debes cambiar esta línea:

```js
const array2 = array1;
```

Por esta otra:

```js
const array2 = [...array1];
```

Es decir, quedándonos el siguiente resultado:

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 130, 44];

const array2 = [...array1];
const found = array2.findIndex(element => element === 12);

if (found > -1) {
  array2.splice(found, 1);
}

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

### Referencias

1. [Sintaxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo amigo, al final lo resolví de esta manera : const array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1)); , con esto pude clonar un objeto que tuviera arrays adentro, ahora ya puedo eliminar posiciones de los arrays en mi copia sin que afecte al original, al inicio creí que el problema pasaba solo con el array y por eso en mi ejemplo puse ese ejemplo básico, pero al final en realidad era todo un objeto que tenía que clonar y que tenía arrays adentro.

Comment: Hola, @zRoyer94. Recuerda que ese método puede llegar a consumir recursos de hardware porque primero lo convierte en una cadena y luego en un array. La idea del operador de propagación es evitar justamente eso, porque en lugar de copiar su referencia se copia el array.

Comment: gracias por la información lo tendré en cuenta, pero por el momento es el único método que me ha funcionado en una funcionalidad urgente que tenía.